# Why isn't the program waiting for the pthread

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

The program isn't executing the whole for-loop of function 1.
I thought joining the thread would make the program wait for the tread to end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* func1(void* arg) {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        printf("Func 1: %d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void func2(void) {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        printf("Func 2: %d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t new_thread;
    pthread_create(&new_thread, NULL, func1, NULL);
    func2();
    pthread_join(&new_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try to compile with `-Wall` and fix those errors?

Comment: Read your compiler warnings. They are there to help you.

Answer (score 5):

From [`pthread_join`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html):

```
   int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
```

As you can see, the first arugment is a `pthread_t` but you're passing `pthread_t*` - that's the issue. So you should use:

```
pthread_join(new_thread, NULL);
```

Note that if you have error checked the `pthread_*` function calls, you'd have found the problem. For example, run your code with:

```
errno = pthread_join(&new_thread, NULL);
if (errno) perror("pthread_join");
```

and see what it says.

Similarly, enabling compiler warnings (such as `-Wall -Wextra`) would help, too.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. note the use of appropriate horizontal and vertical spacing for readability by us humans
4. note the preferred method of exiting a thread.

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>


void* func1( void* arg ) 
{
    (void)arg;  // to avoid compiler warning about unused parameter
    
    for( int i=0; i<10; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "Func 1: %d\n", i );
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}


void func2( void ) 
{
    for( int i=0; i<5; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "Func 2: %d\n", i );
        sleep(1);
    }
}


int main( void ) 
{
    pthread_t new_thread;
    pthread_create( &new_thread, NULL, func1, NULL );
    func2();
    pthread_join( new_thread, NULL );
    return 0;
}
```

A typical run of the proposed code results in:

```
Func 2: 0
Func 1: 0
Func 2: 1
Func 1: 1
Func 2: 2
Func 1: 2
Func 2: 3
Func 1: 3
Func 2: 4
Func 1: 4
Func 1: 5
Func 1: 6
Func 1: 7
Func 1: 8
Func 1: 9
```